# Command-line font information utility

Tags: linux, command-line, font-utility, metadata, font

I'd like a command-line utility which takes a font filename (or base filename if the font spans multiple files) and prints information/meta data about the font: Family name, foundry name, copyright notice, license, available character ranges, weights, font file format and version, etc.

Hardware: x86, x86_64 at least
OS: Linux at least, preferably cross-platform
Price: Gratis
License: Preferably some kind of libre license